# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\jagrelot\workspace\AntBuildExample\chromedriver.exe with ChromeDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to run Selenium within Eclipse, I get a The driver executable does not exist: error. I've ensured that the path to the exe is correct and that the environment PATH variable is set. The error is referencing an older location of the driver which was located in the workspace of the Java project. It seems to be working when I run it through the command line. Are there any suggestions to get the code to run in Eclipse properly?

```
public WebDriver chromeDriver;

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTestsetUp(){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();


    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
    FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTestsetUp
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\jagrelot\workspace\AntBuildExample\chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: Clearly your path is getting set elsewhere. Debug your script and find it. We can't find it with the info you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

The code block you have provided is not sufficient to analyze the root cause. How ever the following points are pretty much evident :

1. The initialization of **`ChromeDriver`** is error prone, it should have been :

   ```
   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   ```
2. As per best practices we should use the **`WebDriver`** interface instead of the **`ChromeDriver`** implementation :

   ```
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   ```
3. As you are seeing the error as **`IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\jagrelot\workspace\AntBuildExample\chromedriver.exe`** which clearly indicates your script is looking for the **`chromedriver`** binary in a different location other than the mentioned one. Probably its due to `error prone` code of **`setProperty`**.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I just ended up creating a new project. I also was using Linux, so the path needed to be defined differently.